# C# Count the words in a string

Tags: c#

How do I do this with basic string functions and loop? I want to count the words in a string. My problem is that it only works when the user do not use multiple spaces.

Here is my code:

```
        string phrase;
        int word = 1;


        Console.Write("Enter a phrase: ");
        phrase = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i<phrase.Length; i++)
        {
            if (name[i] == ' ')
            {
                word++;
            } 
        }
        Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Comment: check the _previous_ element - if it's a space as well, you know you don't have a new word.

Comment: `phrase.Split(' ').Count()`

Comment: Split(' ') won't fix the issue with multiple spaces.

Comment: @TeodorVladutu - a better option would be this: `phrase.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length` to remove multiple spaces, and also don't use `Count()` when you have `Length`

Comment: `var words = phrase.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` Will remove dupes.

Comment: we are not allowed to use  "StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries" :((

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the for loop you could use Split() and Linq:

```
var splitPhrase = phrase.Split(' ');
var wordCount = splitPhrase.Count(x=>x != "");
```

or use StringSplitOptions, as per comment:

```
var words = phrase.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntrie);
var wordCount = words.Count();
```

Comment: This does not cover the issue of having multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` ? =)

Comment: It does deal with multiple spaces. The Linq statement does  filter empty results, which are the result of multiple sapces.

Comment: You are right. Too hasty from side.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a regular expression to "condense" all consecutive spaces into a single instance. Then the job is simple.

```
var str = "aaa bb      cccc d    e";
var regex = new Regex(@"\s+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(str, " ")?.Split(' ')?.Count());
```

Comment: we are not allowed to use reger and var. But thank you!

Comment: I am so used to doing this that I forgot `SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, which is a simpler option indeed.

Comment: we are also not allowed to use that :(( only much more basic string functions

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LINQ, i suggest this approach:

```
    string[] source = phrase.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var matchQuery = from word in source
                     select word;
    
    int wordCount = matchQuery.Count();
    Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have to *define* word. If word is

> Any non empty sequence of letters

we can use a simple *regular expression* pattern: `\p{L}+`

**Code:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

int word = Regex.Matches(phrase, @"\p{L}+").Count;
```

**Edit:** in case you don't want *regular expressions* you can implement *FSM* - **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine:

```
  int word = 0; 
  bool inWord = false;

  foreach (var c in phrase) 
    if (char.IsLetter(c)) {
      if (!inWord) // we count beginnings of each word
        word += 1;

      inWord = true;
    }
    else
      inWord = false;
```

Here we have two states: - `inWord == true, false` - which are if character is within some word or not. Having these states we can count all the words beginnings.

Comment: what does L stand for in C# regex syntax ?

Comment: we are not allowed to use Regex but thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Veverke: `p{...}` stands for *unicode category*, `\p{L}` stands fro unicode category "Letter"

Comment: @x456l: if you are not allowed to use regular expressions, you can try Finite State Machine; please, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array with string data type. Then I would use Split method when reading the data. This would split the entire text anytime you see a defined character (character is a one letter or character). In your case the defined character would be empty space; that is ' '. So my formula would be something like:

```
     string phrase;
     string[] seperated;    // this is where you would split the full name
     int word = 1;


        Console.Write("Enter a phrase: ");
        phrase = Console.ReadLine();
        seperated=phrase.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i<seperated.Length; i++)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(seperated[i]); // this would print each word one by one
        }
```

Once capture the full name split in seperated array, than you can use the seperated name, last name etc the way you want. seperated[0]= would be the first word, seperated[1] would be the second word... if the name consists of total 5 words than the last word could be reached by seperated[4].

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex pattern:
\S matches anything but a whitespace

```
string str = "Test words   test"    
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(str, @"[\S]+");
int numberOfWords = collection.Count;
```

Comment: `"This is a counterexample ! - it is . . ."`, note that `[\S]+` is *too wide* and matches punctuation as well as letters

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following function.It only returns the no. of words in the given sentence.

```
public int totalWords(string sentence) {
            int wordCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (sentence[i] == ' ' && Char.IsLetter(sentence[i + 1]) && (i > 0))
                {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
            wordCount++;
            return wordCount;
        }
```

Comment: It also works fine for multiple spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your words are separated by a space you can just `Split` the string and get the length of the resulting array:

```
string[] words = phrase.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int numberOfWords = words.Length;
```